# JavaScript Bootstrap validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I am using JavaScript and Bootstrap for validation in my form. Everything works the way it should when I make all of these 4 fields required.

However, I need an either/or situation. For example, if the first two fields, 'name' and 'SIN' are filled, then 'BusinessName' and 'BusinessID' are not required and vice versa. Here is the current code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="name" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">SIN #</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SIN" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Business Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BusinessName" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Business #</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Businessid" />
    </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',

        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },

                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z-\.\ ]+$/,
                        message: 'The Name can only consist of Alphabets, Space and Hyphens'
                    }
                }
            },


            SIN: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The SIN is required and cannot be empty'
                    },

                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[0-9\ ]+$/,
                        message: 'The SIN can only consist of Numbers and Space'
                    }
                }
            },


            BusinessName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Business name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }

            },


            Businessid: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Business# is required and cannot be empty'
                    },

                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                        message: 'The Business# can only consist of Numbers'
                    }
                }
            },
des1: {

}


        }
    }) .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
fields: function(){

    if(your evaluator here){

        return name: {etc}

    }
    else{

        return BusinessName: {etc}

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work because in this case, "fields" should being called as "fields()" and maybe bootsrap validator just call "fields".

Comment: Thanks for the reply bb.dd, I get an error when I try this: `fields: function(){

    if (typeof name != 'undefined' && name != null ){
        return name: {....validation` It says there is an error on the return line. Anything I am missing?

Comment: I will answer that: it should be if($.trim($("input[name='name']").val()) == ""){return bussinessName...}else{return name...}

Comment: Still getting the same error when I add that if statement in. What else could be causing it? I only get a syntax error on the first return line.

Comment: Review carefully the syntax, copy/paste the second return line and made the required asjustments. Syntax error are the easiest to tackle. Yet, be aware that this solution could not achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/4jcdnn14/

.on('change', '[name="isPerson"]', function () {

```
    var bootstrapValidator = $('#form_signup').data('bootstrapValidator'),
        isPerson = ($(this).val() == 'true');

    if (isPerson) {
        $('.persona').find('.form-control').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.azienda').find('.form-control').attr('disabled', 'disabled');


        bootstrapValidator.enableFieldValidators('luogo_di_nascita', true)
            .enableFieldValidators('data_di_nascita', true)
            .enableFieldValidators('cf', true)
            .enableFieldValidators('sede', false)
            .enableFieldValidators('ragione_sociale', false);

        bootstrapValidator.revalidateField('luogo_di_nascita')
            .revalidateField('data_di_nascita')
            .revalidateField('cf');

    } else {
        $('.azienda').find('.form-control').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.persona').find('.form-control').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        bootstrapValidator.enableFieldValidators('luogo_di_nascita', false)
            .enableFieldValidators('data_di_nascita', false)
            .enableFieldValidators('cf', false)
            .enableFieldValidators('sede', true)
            .enableFieldValidators('ragione_sociale', true);

        bootstrapValidator.revalidateField('sede')
            .revalidateField('ragione_sociale');

    }






    })
```

According to the value of "isPerson", only a part of the field is validated.